# Can't show data when searching by value in firebase android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, onclicklistener, event-listener

I have a program android based on firebase. This program is to show data when button search is clicked. But the data doesn't display it.

I think the problem is on the function reference.AddValueEventListener. Here's the code

```
package love.trykamus;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {    
    private static final String TAG = "ViewDatabase";
    RecyclerView recyclerview;
    FirebaseDatabase database;
    DatabaseReference reference;
    Kamus kamus;
    List<Kamus> kamusList;
    EditText search;
    Button btn;
    TextView tvNgoko;
    private String key, kramal, kraming,ngoko;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        search = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search);
        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
        tvNgoko = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ngoko);
        kamus = new Kamus();
        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        recyclerview = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rview);
        reference = database.getReference("employees");


        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                kamusList = new ArrayList<>();
                // StringBuffer stringbuffer = new StringBuffer();
                for(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 :dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

                    kamus = dataSnapshot1.getValue(Kamus.class);
                    String indonesia=kamus.getIndonesia();
                    String kramaAlus=kamus.getKramaAlus();
                    String kramaInggil=kamus.getKramaInggil();
                    String ngoko=kamus.getNgoko();
                    kamus.setIndonesia(indonesia);
                    kamus.setKramaAlus(kramaAlus);
                    kamus.setKramaInggil(kramaInggil);
                    kamus.setNgoko(ngoko);

                    kamusList.add(kamus);

                    // Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,""+name,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }

                KamusAdapter recycler = new KamusAdapter(kamusList);
                RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutmanager = new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this);
                recyclerview.setLayoutManager(layoutmanager);
                recyclerview.setItemAnimator( new DefaultItemAnimator());
                recyclerview.setAdapter(recycler);

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
                // Failed to read value
                //  Log.w(TAG, "Failed to read value.", error.toException());
            }
        });

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                  key = search.getText().toString();
                  kamus.setIndonesia(key);
                if(key == kamus.getIndonesia()){
                    reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            for(DataSnapshot ds :dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                                kamus = ds.getValue(Kamus.class);
                                kamus.setKramaAlus(ds.child(key).getValue(Kamus.class).getKramaAlus());
                                kamus.setKramaInggil(ds.child(key).getValue(Kamus.class).getKramaInggil());
                                kamus.setKramaInggil(ds.child(key).getValue(Kamus.class).getNgoko());

                                tvNgoko.setText(kamus.getNgoko());

                                Log.d(TAG, "showData: name: " + kamus.getKramaAlus());
                                Log.d(TAG, "showData: name: " + kamus.getKramaInggil());
                                Log.d(TAG, "showData: name: " + kamus.getNgoko());
                            }

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
                            // Failed to read value
                            //  Log.w(TAG, "Failed to read value.", error.toException());
                        }

                    });
                }

            }
        });




    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
    }
    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
    }
}
```

And the result of the program is

```
06-07 15:04:45.484 24544-24544/love.trykamus E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: love.trykamus, PID: 24544
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String love.trykamus.Kamus.getKramaAlus()' on a null object reference
    at love.trykamus.MainActivity$2$1.onDataChange(MainActivity.java:109)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzfc.zza(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzgx.zzdr(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzhd.run(Unknown Source)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5233)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:898)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:693)
```

This is the 
**Kamus.class**

```
package com.rifkyprayanta.kamusbahasa;

public class Kamus {

public String indonesia;
public String kramaalus;
public String kramainggil;
public String ngoko;

public Kamus(){

}

public Kamus(String indonesia, String kramaalus, String kramainggil, String ngoko) {
    this.indonesia = indonesia;
    this.kramaalus = kramaalus;
    this.kramainggil = kramainggil;
    this.ngoko = ngoko;
}

public String getIndonesia() {
    return indonesia;
}

public void setIndonesia(String indonesia) {
    this.indonesia = indonesia;
}

public String getKramaalus() {
    return kramaalus;
}

public void setKramaalus(String kramaalus) {
    this.kramaalus = kramaalus;
}

public String getKramainggil() {
    return kramainggil;
}

public void setKramainggil(String kramainggil) {
    this.kramainggil = kramainggil;
}

public String getNgoko() {
    return ngoko;
}

public void setNgoko(String ngoko) {
    this.ngoko = ngoko;
}
```

}

And then this is the firebase struktur

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jPdun.png)

Comment: could you post you database structure as well?

Comment: hi, to solve this please share with us Kamus.class and your database structure in firebase

Comment: You have two `onDataChange` methods. Which one is throwing the exception? As both Levi and Gastón have asked, please update your question to also include the relevant part of your database (as text, no screenshots). You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Answer (score 0):

Replace this code....

```
  reference = database.getReference().child("employees");
  with      
  reference = database.getReference("employees");
```

Comment: hi, this is the same as getReference() will get the main tree node to start querying by the next child, and getReference("") will just start your reference from employees and is not a good practice since you are declaring a global reference to the entire database to then start querying your childs from it

Comment: if this is main node then i think no need to pass any argument in .getReference() is sufficient to access

Comment: but op needs to access employees, leaving getReference() alone will just reference to the entire database

Comment: that's why i add one child  because i think after  whole link he has only one child employee.

Comment: is the same, starting from employees as reference or pointing it out with a child , but is not a good practice declaring global database reference to a certain node

Comment: yes i know . thanks buddy, but i,m just giving solution acc to his problem question

Comment: no problem, im just saying that this is redundant and the problem will persist